# Decorator Methods Design Decision in Python

Tags: python

Decorator pattern takes your function, decorates it with something else and returns you a new decorated function, and this is something I understand.

But when it comes to Python, I found the implementation of decorators little different. Let's say we have the following code:

```
def helloWorld(func):
    print(func() + 1)

@helloWorld
def hello():
    return 2
```

My basic expectation was to call this method by saying `hello()` however, it somewhat worked with the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    hello()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

So basically, when it hits `hello` part of `hello()`, it prints the correct result and returns `None` as any function without `return` statement does in Python. `()` is trying to invoke a `None` in this case. So I did this and it worked as I expected:

```
def helloWorld(func):
    def inside():
        print(func() + 1)
    return inside

@helloWorld
def hello():
    return 2

hello()
```

I am not sure whether my expectation justifies anything here. But as a person coming from C#, Java, etc. background, I found this little different. I was expecting the same behavior of the second code sample in the first one. What am I missing? Why was this designed in this way? Why is just saying `hello` is enough to invoke decorator function? What good does this design have?

### Update and Clarification

I was expecting it to work without specifically returning a nested function in the decorator. So in the first example, `hello()` could have worked as if `helloWorld` was returning a nested method.

Comment: It is not clear why you expected different; as you put it, a decorator function "returns you a new decorated function", and your first version *doesn't* return a function. Also, `hello` didn't take arguments; `hello(number = 2)` was never going to work.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I was using the wrong error message. Fixed it.

Comment: Still, `helloWorld` doesn't `return` anything explicitly, so decorating `hello` with it is just setting `hello = None`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: How do you call methods that return nothing. Do you call them without `()`?

Comment: It is not the call to `helloWorld`, which returns `None`, that is the problem; it's the subsequent calls to `hello`, which *is* `None`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
@helloWorld
def hello():
    return 2
```

Python does

```
def hello():
    return 2
hello = helloWorld(hello)
```

So hello will contain whatever helloWorld returns, in your first case you didn't return anything (which is the same as returning `None`). That's why calling `hello()` would give the error 'NoneType' object is not callable.

Comment: Right. Decorators are just syntactic sugar for the second code block posted in this answer. If your decorator doesn't return anything explicitly, it implicitly returns `None`, which means the function you're trying to decorate gets assigned to None.